# Is “fulfill” in Matthew 5.17 the underlining concept of “obey?”

Tags: jesus, luke

Matthew 5.17 reads: Think not that I am come to destroy the law, or the prophets: I am not come to destroy, but to fulfill [the law]. (KJV, emphasis mine)